# Updating to Android Studio 0.8.16 fails because of unexpected uninstall.exe file

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

When I tried to update Android Studio to the *0.8.14* release, I got an error that said there was an unexpected file called `uninstall.exe`. The suggested solution was to delete the file. The patch failed because it couldn't delete this file.

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
Temp. directory: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\

java.io.IOException: Cannot delete file C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.replaceUpdated(BaseUpdateAction.java:66)
    at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:57)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:184)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch$3.forEach(Patch.java:273)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:324)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:268)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:84)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:75)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:287)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:18)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner$2.execute(Runner.java:253)
    at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$5.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Running Android Studio as an administrator solved it. Hope it helps you too :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PieterGoosen, it might be a short answer but it does appear to answer the question (you need to run Andriod Studio as an admin).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I keep getting the error `Cannot delete file` for different files in the `~\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\plugins\svn4idea\lib` directory.

Comment: Nevermind. After at least 4-5 attempts of trying to update AS, it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the operate system（E.g. windows10), the system has updated recently，or updating in background. It satuation makes system files change to read-only.You can fix it that download and install the newset android studio in web.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is ensuring plugins folder isn't read-only and Running Android Studio as administrator.
THis solved the issue, at least for me

Answer (score 0):

Updating JDK to the last version solves this problem, currently [1.8.0_25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), *Regards*